# Запуск android приложений Qt в Genymotion

Tags: android, qt, genymotion

В Qt настроено вроде все: установлен jdk, Android sdk, android-ndk, apache-ant. Также установлен Genymotion. Но после удачной компиляции любого приложения в Qt (пробовались приложения "Hello world" с использованием QML, также на просто виджетах, потом пробовалось приложение из примеров Qt Калькулятор на QML), запуская его в Genymotion происходит вылетание установленной программы в Android, либо система сама перезагружается. Какие могут быть причины этого казуса?

Вот что выдает Qt при запуске приложения:

```
Запуск внешнего процесса.D/dalvikvm( 1563): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/ActivityManager(  526): Start proc org.qtproject.example.a321 for activity org.qtproject.example.a321/org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity: pid=1563     uid=10058 gids={50058, 3003, 1028, 1015}
W/Bundle  ( 1563): Key android.app.lib_name expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
W/Bundle  ( 1563): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
W/Bundle  ( 1563): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1121)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.loadApplication(QtActivity.java:225)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.startApp(QtActivity.java:655)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:895)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
W/Bundle  ( 1563):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 281K, 9% free 3688K/4036K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 8ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0xa506dcd8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Core.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Core.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0xa506dcd8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Network.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Network.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Network.so 0xa506dcd8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0xa506dcd8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0xa506dcd8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0xa506dcd8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so 0xa506dcd8
I/Qt      ( 1563): qt start
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so 0xa506dcd8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0xa506dcd8
D/dalvikvm( 1563): Shared lib '/data/data/org.qtproject.example.a321/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so' already loaded in same CL 0xa506dcd8
W/System.err( 1563): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.getClass(ExtractStyle.java:388)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.<init>(ExtractStyle.java:92)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtActivityDelegate.loadApplication(QtActivityDelegate.java:430)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.loadApplication(QtActivity.java:245)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.startApp(QtActivity.java:655)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:895)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 1563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
W/System.err( 1563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
W/System.err( 1563):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable
W/System.err( 1563):    ... 25 more
W/System.err( 1563): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file     "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.a321-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.a321-1, /system/lib]]
W/System.err( 1563):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
W/System.err( 1563):    ... 25 more
W/System.err( 1563): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.getClass(ExtractStyle.java:388)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.<init>(ExtractStyle.java:93)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtActivityDelegate.loadApplication(QtActivityDelegate.java:430)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.loadApplication(QtActivity.java:245)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.startApp(QtActivity.java:655)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:895)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 1563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
W/System.err( 1563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
W/System.err( 1563):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedStateListDrawable
W/System.err( 1563):    ... 25 more
W/System.err( 1563): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable" on path: DexPathList[[    zip file "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.a321-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.a321-1, /system/lib]]
W/System.err( 1563):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
W/System.err( 1563):    ... 25 more
W/System.err( 1563): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.getClass(ExtractStyle.java:388)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.<init>(ExtractStyle.java:94)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtActivityDelegate.loadApplication(QtActivityDelegate.java:430)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.loadApplication(QtActivity.java:245)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.startApp(QtActivity.java:655)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:895)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 1563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
W/System.err( 1563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
W/System.err( 1563):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable
W/System.err( 1563):    ... 25 more
W/System.err( 1563): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file     "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.a321-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.a321-1, /system/lib]]
W/System.err( 1563):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
W/System.err( 1563):    ... 25 more
W/ResourceType( 1563): Skipping entry 0x1080526 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 234K, 8% free 3933K/4232K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 8ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 61K, 7% free 4192K/4488K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 198K, 6% free 4415K/4696K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 5ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 315K, 9% free 4339K/4744K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1563): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.626MB for 349068-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 9% free 4679K/5088K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 23K, 9% free 4657K/5088K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1563): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.937MB for 349068-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 4998K/5432K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 4998K/5432K, paused 8ms, total 9ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1563): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.270MB for 349068-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 5339K/5776K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 5339K/5776K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1563): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.603MB for 349068-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 5680K/6120K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 5681K/6120K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1563): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.937MB for 349068-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 6022K/6464K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 6364K/6808K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 6705K/7152K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 214K, 6% free 7273K/7700K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 513K, 7% free 7970K/8548K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 7ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 500K, 7% free 8912K/9496K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 4ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 804K, 9% free 9859K/10728K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 8ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1980K, 18% free 9872K/11912K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 8ms
D/dalvikvm( 1563): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 452K, 12% free 10669K/12008K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
D/libEGL  ( 1563): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
D/        ( 1563): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8c9b2d8, tid 1563
D/libEGL  ( 1563): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
D/libEGL  ( 1563): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
W/EGL_genymotion( 1563): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
E/OpenGLRenderer( 1563): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
E/OpenGLRenderer( 1563): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
E/OpenGLRenderer( 1563): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
E/OpenGLRenderer( 1563): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
D/OpenGLRenderer( 1563): Enabling debug mode 0
W/System.err( 1563): java.lang.Exception: Can't find main library 'null'
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative.startApplication(QtNative.java:203)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtActivityDelegate$4.run(QtActivityDelegate.java:785)
W/System.err( 1563):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtLayout.onSizeChanged(QtLayout.java:71)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:14932)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:14905)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14813)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
W/System.err( 1563):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 1563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 1563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
W/System.err( 1563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
W/System.err( 1563):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/InputMethodManagerService(  526): Focus gain on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@529a6848 (uid=10058 pid=1563)
I/AndroidRuntime( 1563): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
I/ActivityManager(  526): Process org.qtproject.example.a321 (pid 1563) has died.


«org.qtproject.example.a321» завершился крахом.
```

Comment: Стек трейс ошибки покажите.